# Shiny App Producing GT Table that is too low on Page

Tags: r, shiny, gt

I have a Shiny App that has multiple different features, but one the user selects a name and it produces a tall GT table dependent on them. However the table is far too low on tge page ass seen in the photo below: [image]

I want it to align to the top of the page.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
     .gt-output-container {
       margin-top: 0px; /* Reduce top margin */
      padding-top: 0px; /* Reduce top padding */
    }
  "))
),

 theme = bs_theme(
   bg = "white",
   fg = "#003366",
  primary = "#003366",
  secondary = "#CC0033"
),
titlePanel("Title"),
fluidRow(
column(4, 
       selectInput("plotType", "Select Plot Type", choices = c("Trends", "Movement Plot", "Percentiles"), selected = "Trends"),
       
       # Conditional Panel for selecting pitcher - shown for all plot types
       selectInput("pitcher", "Select Pitcher", choices = unique(data$Pitcher)),
       
       # Other selections only shown for Trends and Movement Plot
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.plotType != 'Percentiles'",
         selectInput("dates", "Select Dates", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
         selectInput("gameType", "Select Game Type", choices = c("Both", unique(data$GameType)), selected = "Both"),
         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.plotType == 'Trends'",
           selectInput("dataPoint", "Select Data Point", choices = c("RelSpeed", "InducedVertBreak", "HorzBreak", "SpinRate", "RelHeight", "RelSide", "Extension"))
         )
       )
),
column(8,
       plotlyOutput("trendPlot"),
       tableOutput("averageTable"),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.plotType == 'Percentiles'",
         div(gt_output("percentilePlot"), class = "gt-output-container")
       )
)
 )
)
```

This is my UI Code... I can attach the GT Code if nec, have tried multiple CSS solutions but nothing has worked.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).